# SBT How get filename in folder with match?

Tags: scala, sbt

I need find filename in folder (in build.sbt), and add in artifact list.

```
//in build.sbt
val myZipTask = taskKey[File]("return the bundle:dist-zip file")

myZipTask := {
    val filesArray = new java.io.File("/target/bundle").listFiles()
    //here need to find the file name by coincidence and convert to a string
    file(fileName)
}; addArtifact( Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), myZipTask)
```

I tried this option

```
//in build.sbt
val myZipTask = taskKey[File]("return the bundle:dist-zip file")

myZipTask := {
  import java.io.File

  def getListOfFiles(dir: String): List[String] = {
    val file = new File(dir)
    file.listFiles.filter(_.isFile)
      .filter(_.getName.startsWith("startName"))
      .map(_.getPath).toList
  }
  getListOfFiles("/target/bundle")
}; addArtifact( Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), myZipTask)
```

And sbt return me error:

```
build.sbt: error: type mismatch;
found   : List[String]
required: sbt.File
(which expands to)  java.io.File
getListOfFiles("/target/bundle")
              ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation on [Path Finders](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Paths.html#Path+Finders):

```
val finder: PathFinder = target.value / "bundle"
```

You can add `* "startName*"` if you want to filter by prefix. If you call `finder.get`, it will return you a `Seq[File]`, so this is what you wanted from your `getListOfFiles`.

But the problem with your code is that you need to return one file, not a list. You could either output an error if the file doesn't exist:

```
finder.get.headOption.getOrElse {
  sys.error("Couldn't find bundle dist-zip file")
}
```

or change you task type to `Option[File]`, return `finder.get.headOption` and add the artifact only if the file is there:

```
myZipTask.value.foreach { zipFile =>
  addArtifact(Artifact("bundle", "zip", "zip"), zipFile)
}
```

This `foreach` could work even for multiple files if that's an option in your usecase.

Comment: I see that you split your question in two. The answer to the other one makes this one obsolete in your particular use case, but taking into account the context of this question on its own, I think `PathFilder`s is the way to go.